# How to make calls from android app

Tags: java, android

Im trying to make an app with buttons to call different phone numbers. I have this:
     package com.BigTooth.Apps.Recromax;

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.*;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    private void phoneCall1()
    {
        String phoneCallUri = "tel:4078421430";
        Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
        startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
    }
    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    private void phoneCall()
    {
        String phoneCallUri = "tel:8889807091";
        Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
        startActivity(phoneCallIntent);}
    } 
}
```

In my MainActivity.java file. Its telling me that isn't correct. Please help!!!

Comment: Please post the Logcat output. Also, do you have `CALL_PRIVILEGED` permission in your Manifest?

Comment: Your `button.setOnClickListener`is outside any function.. in wrong scope.. put it in onCreate.. and phoneCall function is all messy too.. too much copypaste.. try to learn some basics before starting to copypaste :)

Comment: I do have the permissions in my manifest

Answer (score 1):

`button.setOnClickListener` is in the wrong place. Also, the onClickListener is a bit wring. Should be:

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.*;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.youButtonId);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.youButtonId1);
        // add button listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                phoneCall();
            }
        });
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                phoneCall1();
            }
        });
    }
    private void phoneCall()
    {
        String phoneCallUri = "tel:8889807091";
        Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
        startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
    }
    private void phoneCall1()
    {
        String phoneCallUri = "tel:4078421430";
        Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
        startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its telling me that    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { is an error

Comment: yep. Sorry, my fault. I added a curly brace (I shouldn't have removed it)

Comment: Ok. I added the code for the button (you just have to correct the `youButtonId` part and put the correct one depending on you layout). I'm going to bed already, because missing so many things isn't normal.

Comment: also, should join `phoneCall()` and `phoneCall1()` into a new `phoneCall(String number)`. Not necessary, but recommended.

Comment: Now it says I must implement the abstract method android.view.View.OnClickListener.onClick

Comment: nope. You copied an old version of the code (shame on me...)

Comment: I mean, the one in the answer is right now (it was already a question of self-pride)